# I can't get any closure so to speak

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I know this kind of question has been asked a thousand times before, I read a ton of posts on this but I still can't wrap my head around it. Tried many examples without success on my own before posting here.

I'm basically trying to return images from different folders but I need to process the images from each directory separately in a specific way. I am not very familiar with json and ajax in general so this might be why I don't understand this too well.

Anyhow, my idea was to simply create a for loop and then for each directory, get the images via ajax and deal with them.

Obviously this ain't working as I expected and I read somewhere that I need a javascript "closure" to get this to work but it never works. Here is my basic code without closure:

```
$.getJSON('/img/content/galleries/', function(directories) {
    for (var dirnum = 2; dirnum < directories.length - 1; dirnum++) {
        var folder = '/img/content/galleries/' + directories[dirnum] + '/';

        $.ajax({
            url: folder,
            success: function(data) {
                    $("#gallery").text("");
                    $(data).find("a").attr("href", function(i, val) {
                        if (val.match(/\.jpg|\.png|\.gif/)) {
                            $("#gallery").append("<img src='" + folder + val + "'>");
                        }
                    }); // end data.find
                } // end success
        }); // end ajax

    } // end for loop


}); // end getJSON
```

This code runs but always give me the results of gallery2 before gallery1 (the name of my directories) and then gives an error saying it can't find images from gallery1 inside the gallery2 folder...

If anybody can help me insert some kind of closure in here that would be great. A few hours already wasted with no results so far. I just don't get that concept I guess.

Also note that I previously get the "directories" values from a php file in the parent folder of gallery1 and gallery 2 that has that code in it:

```
<?php
$directories = scandir('.');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($directories);
?>
```

Or if you guys think there is a simpler way to approach this in javascript I'm all ears! I know I could have done it a different way with php intermixed with some javascript but I wanted to use javascript only here.

Thanks a bunch in advance.

Erick P.

Answer (score 1):

Major flaw is each request empties the container ... so only content from last request received will be displayed.

Fix that by emptying container before the request loop starts

You can't control order of requests received ... so if order is important will need to use promises for the requests in order to make sure data is populated in correct order

```
$.getJSON('/img/content/galleries/', function(directories) {

    //empty container before starting request loop
    $("#gallery").empty(); 



    for (var dirnum = 2; dirnum < directories.length - 1; dirnum++) {


   // wrap ajax in IIFE closure
    (function(dirnum){

     var folder = '/img/content/galleries/' + directories[dirnum] + '/';

        $.ajax({
            url: folder,
            success: function(data) {
                    //$("#gallery").text("");// move up above loop
                    $(data).find("a").attr("href", function(i, val) {
                        if (val.match(/\.jpg|\.png|\.gif/)) {
                            $("#gallery").append("<img src='" + folder + val + "'>");
                        }
                    }); // end data.find
                } // end success
        }); // end ajax


     })(dirnum);//end closure in for loop

    } // end for loop


}); // end getJSON
```

Not quite sure why you start at third index for `dirnum`....assume you have unwanted paths in the `directories` array. Would be cleaner to filter those at server

Comment: Thanks charlie. That was so dumb of me. Can't believe I didn't see this. While this answers part of the problem, I still have the same issue with some of the links taking pictures from the wrong directory. I do think if I try some of the "closures" I've tried before, it might work now. I'll see how I go.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Charlie for the help! I fixed it via the closure as everyone told me:

```
$.getJSON('/img/content/galleries/', function(directories) {
    $("#gallery").text("");
    for (var dirnum = 2; dirnum < directories.length - 1; dirnum++) {
        (function(dirnum) {
            var folder = '/img/content/galleries/' + directories[dirnum] + '/';
            $.ajax({
                url: folder,
                success: function(data) {
                        $(data).find("a").attr("href", function(i, val) {
                            if (val.match(/\.jpg|\.png|\.gif/)) {
                                $("#gallery").append("<img src='" + folder + val + "'>");
                            }
                        }); // end data.find
                    } // end success
            }); // end ajax
        })(dirnum);
    } // end for loop
}); // end getJSON
```

Charlie I'll try your solution also to check as another alternative. Thanks again!

Erick